# Bootstrap 3 Navbar dropdown problem

Tags: templating, entries, structure, navigation

I have included the navigation using Bootstrap 3 navbar. It is put together using Craft entries. I need the 'What we do' dropdown to be triggered when pressing the text or caret arrow but at the minute they are displaying as two different menu li as shown.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('navigation') %}

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-ptm" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="{{ siteUrl }}assets/images/logo.png" width="300px;" alt="PTM Calibration Logo"/></a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="collapse-ptm">
            {% nav entry in entries %}

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a> {% ifchildren %}
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            {% children %}
                        </ul>
                        {% endifchildren %}
                    </li>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {% endnav %}
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If i'm understanding this correctly, it looks like you just have your loop starting a little early in the markup, so at the moment you are creating a new `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` item for every entry.

Does moving the `{% nav entry in entries %}` loop within the first `<ul>` help at all? like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 {% nav entry in entries %}
     <li>
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
        {% ifchildren %}
           <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               {% children %}
              </ul>
           </li>
        {% endifchildren %}
     </li>
 {% endnav %}
</ul>
```

**Additionally**

Whilst writing this answer out I noticed that your `{% endifchildren %}` tag comes before a closing `</li>` tag, so it might just be that:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
     <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
     {% ifchildren %}
       <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              {% children %}
           </ul>
          {# endifchildren was originally here #}
        </li>
     {% endifchildren %}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried both answers above but they don't seem to change it at all. The <ul class="nav navbar-nav"> is being duplicated for each entry which isn't ideal. If I could just get the dropdown arrow 'caret' to join the entry with the dropdown items and not make it's own entry it would work ok.

Answer (score 2):

I'm viewing this on a phone on a plane right now (forgive the terrible explanation), but it looks like your `<li class="dropdown">` is being toggled on the children. The .dropdown class needs to be added on the parent  `<li>` item.

Because it is being toggled on the first child, that is why your caret is being rendered as a separate nav link.

Comment: I actually tried moving it to the parent <li> item and then removing the .dropdown class completely and it doesn't change at all. The caret is still rendered separately unfortunately.